# Eureka Forms: How to change form global tint colour

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am using Eureka to implement a simple form in my project. The form seems to have blue tint in the tint bar buttons above the keyboard and I am unsure how to change it.

[image]

Is there a way to make the "Done" label green like the rest of my UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated Eureka 4.3.x

You should override a variable **customNavigationAccessoryView** in your controller

```
override var customNavigationAccessoryView: (UIView & NavigationAccessory)? {
    // The width might not be correctly defined yet: (Normally you can use UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let navView = NavigationAccessoryView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 44.0))
    navView.barTintColor = UIColor.MaterialColors.category3
    navView.tintColor = UIColor.white
    return navView
}
```

Here you go and fix the colour of Done Label.
override NaviagtionAccessoryView Instance as navigationAccessoryView below

```
navigationAccessoryView.tintColor = "Your Colour"
navigationAccessoryView.backgroundColor = "Your Colour"
navigationAccessoryView.doneButton.tintColor = "Your Colour"
```

[More Here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#configuring-the-keyboard-navigation-accesory)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default tint color for all UIView instance by

```
UIView.appearance().tintColor = .red
```

appearance() is a method in UIAppearance protocol. UIView and its subclasses confirm to this protocol. You can also do

```
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = .green
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool 
{
   self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.black // You can set it to which color you want.
   return true
}
```

All the tint color of the whole app will be changed to the given color.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work for Eureka Forms. It changes tint everywhere except Eureka components.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me perfectly:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    NavigationAccessoryView.appearance().tintColor = /* your color here */
}
```